# Difference between 顔を合わせる and 会う

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I would like to know the difference between 顔を合わせる and 会う

> 彼はそれまで長く親密に交際していた四人の友人たちからある日、我々はみんなもうお前とは**顔を合わせたく**ないし、口をききたくもないと告げられた (from Colorless Tsukuru Tazaki and His Years of Pilgrimage, Haruki Murakami)

I translated as:

> While they were very close for a long time, his
>   friends told me one day they did not want to meet him again

But what brings 顔を合わせる with regards to 会う　?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

会う can mean to meet people by chance as well as deliberately, and it can also mean meeting people without necessarily interacting with them, but 顔を合わせる means to meet someone deliberately and talk to them or interact with them. So "会う" can be "encounter someone" but "顔を合わせる" is more like "interact with someone".